# BlueCloth 2 and unicode

Tags: unicode, markdown, bluecloth

The following Haml causes to a `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError` when the latest BlueCloth (2.0.11) is used for markdown processing under Ruby 1.9.2:

```
:markdown
  résumé
```

Apparently, the humble é character is enough to make BlueCloth throw a fit! Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've worked around this by installing [Maruku](https://github.com/nex3/maruku) and using the `:maruku` filter instead. But this isn't a perfect solution for everyone, so I'd love to see a better answer.